# Putting changelists on another perforce machine

Tags: perforce

I did a migration of the perforce server. Because there are many depots and many data and because our department does not want that the server is down for a day, I did the following:

Step 2 : Stop the 'old' perforce server on machine A
Step 1 : Copy all data from machine A to machine B 
Step 2 : Start again the 'old' server
Setp 3 : Do the complete migration and start the new server at machine B

Now the problem is that in the meanwile, there are several changelists submitted to machine A.

Is there an easy way to copy the changes to machine B ? Note that I have a checkpoint, so the metadata is not the problem.

I know that on version controls like git it is easy with patches. Is such a thing also possible in perforce in an easy way?

Comment: That sounds like a rather esoteric server activity - you'll probably be better off contacting Perforce support directly to see if they have any ideas. The only thing I can suggest is repeating those changes manually on the new server.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at p4 pull and p4 replicate command given by perforce.

[P4 Pull](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/pull.html) and [P4 Replicate](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/replicate.html) are the 2 commands given for purpose like these. I am assuming that your p4 server is p4d 2010.2 or above for these commands.

Also, I would recommend you reading Perforce's knowledge base for their article on [Offline check pointing](http://kb.perforce.com/article/126). This article is not a direct solution to your problem, but it gives you insight of how you may tackle your situation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Did you truncate your journal when you did the first migration?  If so, you can probably replay the latest production journal and then rsync/robocopy the archive content (files in the depots).  That'll let you catch up.

I assume this is a one-off activity?

You should probably check in with Perforce tech support just to make sure you're not overlooking anything.